# PHP MySQLi bind_result null?

Tags: php, mysqli, null, return

I'm writing a class, but I stucked in a function. It requests the email address by username, but it's only returning null.

Code:

```
private function getUserEmail($username){
    if($stmt = $this->_mysqli->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE username='?'")){
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($email);
        $stmt->fetch();
        var_dump($email);
        $stmt->close();
        return $email;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check if the query is actually executing? Actually returning any data? Your code is simply assuming success throughout.

Comment: @MarcB $stmt->execute() returns true.

Comment: I checked if $stmt->fetch returns error, but it returns null, so I think the problem is somwhere there.

Comment: getting `null` from the ->fetch() call means that there's no data at all (or you've fetched all available data already): http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php. Do a `echo $stmt->num_rows()` right after the ->execute() call. If you get 0, then you've just got no data at all.

Comment: It's returning 0, but there's data in the users table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the single quotations around the ?

```
if($stmt = $this->_mysqli->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE username=?")){
```

Otherwise it won't recognize the ? as a placeholder.

See [documentation on syntax here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html): "The ? characters should not be enclosed within quotation marks, even if you intend to bind them to string values."

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help. I removed the quations, and now the code is working.